# Error with RequestHandler.Process VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, api

I am trying to set up the API of World Weather Online in my VB.NET application. As I am quite begginer in VB.NET I am using the code they provide on their website, and I am facing an issue with the class "Premium API", here is the code :

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports System.Threading
Imports EnergyMan_AddIn.premium.pastweather

Public Class PremiumAPI
    Public ApiBaseURL As String =
       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PremiumApiBaseURL")
    Public PremiumAPIKey As String =
       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PremiumAPIKey")

    Public Function GetPastWeather(input As PastWeatherInput) As PastWeather
        ' create URL based on input paramters
        Dim apiURL As String = ApiBaseURL + "past-weather.ashx?q=" + input.query + "&format=" + input.format + "&extra=" + input.extra + "&enddate=" + input.enddate + "&date=" + input.[date] + "&includelocation=" + input.includelocation + "&callback=" + input.callback + "&key=" + PremiumAPIKey

        ' get the web response
        **Dim result As String = RequestHandler.Process(apiURL)**

        ' serialize the json output and parse in the helper class
        Dim pWeather As PastWeather = DirectCast(New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(result, GetType(PastWeather)), PastWeather)

        Return pWeather
    End Function

End Class
```

It say that "process" is not a member of RequestHandler" in "Requesthandler.Process(apiURL)".

Is a reference is missing ?

Edit : Here you will find the link to the code : https://developer.worldweatheronline.com/api/code-examples.aspx

Thank you for you help :)

Comment: If you'd like us to help, you should provide the relevant links in your question.

Comment: If RequestHandler is a Class with a constructor, you should: `Dim MyRequest As New RequestHalder`. If it does what I think it does, you probably need a reference to `System.Net`.

Comment: The problem does not come from RequestHandler but from Process which is not a member of RequestHandler.